# Using an async Task method that calls another Task method - possible to use only one task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I've written a generic async method for getting json from a web API

```
private static async Task<T> WebReq<T>(string url, string method)
    {
        // Init a HttpWebRequest for the call
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = method;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Send request to the internet and wait for the response
            using (var response = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                // Get the datastream
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Read bytes in the responseStream and copy them to the memoryStream 
                    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                }
            }

            // Read from the memoryStream
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                var result = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
            }
        }             
    }
```

This generic method will then be used by all my methods for making calls to the API, eg

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetExampleDictAsync(string id)
    {
        string url = baseUrl + "GetExampleDictionary/" + id;
        return await WebReq<Dictionary<string, string>>(url, "POST");
    }
```

To my understanding, this will be creating 2 tasks. If I were to write out the contents of WebReq each time then it'd only be 1 task per call... How can I use my generic method and only start one Task?

Is it as simple as returning the WebReq without awaiting it?

Comment: Instead of writing such code, I would advise you to have a look at a library like Refit (https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit), which accomplish that kind of tasks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks fine to me and I probably wouldn't change it. If you are concerned, you could change the signature of your second method to:

```
public static Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetExampleDictAsync(string id)
{
    string url = baseUrl + "GetExampleDictionary/" + id;
    return WebReq<Dictionary<string, string>>(url, "POST");
}
```

You are then just returning the Task created by your inner method, which you can await in the caller - there's no need to await it in this method, so it doesn't need to be async.

However, if this method ever needed to do anything *after* the call to `WebReq`, then it would benefit from being async, so I would consider that before changing it.